# Solving a differential equation, second pair of eyes needed.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a simple ODE which contains a constant k.  Solving this ODE gives a solution containing k.  If I set $k=0$ in the solution, I do not get the solution that I get if I set $k=0$ in the original ODE.  I have been through my workings over and over, but can't see the error.  A second pair of eyes please!

Here it is:

$\frac{dT}{dx} = k(T-T_{amb})$ where $T_{amb}=Ax+B$

The boundary condition is:

$T=T_0$ when $x=0$, we need to find $T=T_1$ at $x=L$

Solution for $k\ne0$:

$\frac{dT}{dx} = k(T-(Ax+B)) = kT-kAx-kB$

let $a=k, b=-kA, c=-kB$

So we have to solve: $\frac{dT}{dx} = aT + bx + c$

Solution:

let $v=aT+bx$, so $\frac {dv}{dx}=a\frac {dT}{dx}+b => \frac {dT}{dx}=\frac 1a(\frac {dv}{dx}-b)$

the ODE then becomes: $\frac 1a(\frac {dv}{dx}-b)=v+c$

$=>\frac 1a\frac {dv}{dx}-\frac ba=v+c$

$=>\frac 1a\frac {dv}{dx}=\frac ba+v+c$

$=>\frac {dv}{dx}=a(\frac ba+v+c)$

variable separable, so

$\int_{v_0}^{v_1}\frac{dv}{\frac ba+v+c}=\int_0^L a.dx$

$=>\ln(\frac{\frac ba+v_1+c}{\frac ba+v_0+c})=aL$

back substitute T:

$=>\ln(\frac{\frac ba+aT_1+bL+c}{\frac ba+aT_0+c})=aL$

$=>\frac ba+aT_1+bL+c=e^{aL}(\frac ba+aT_0+c)$

$=>T_1=\frac 1a(e^{aL}(\frac ba+aT_0+c)-\frac ba-bL-c)$

substituting A, B:

$T_1=\frac 1ke^{kL}(-A+kT_0-kB)+A/k+AL+B$

Now for the solution where $k\to0$, one gets, as $e^{kL}\to1$:

$T_1=T_0+AL$

However the solution to the original ODE with $k=0$ gives $\frac{dT}{dx} = 0$

$=>\int_{T_0}^{T_1}dT=0$

$=>T_1=T_0$

Why do I get an extra term $AL$ doing it the first way?

Comment: Sorry but your post virtually unreadable. I can't see what the boundary conditions are.

Comment: $T=T_0$ when $x=0$, need to find $T=T_1$ at $x=L$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ignoring some division-by-zero problems in your limit. While $e^{kL}$ indeed tends to $1$, $1/k$ tends to infinity. The rules for limit arithmetic only apply if the limits of the operands actually exist, the difference between two "non-identical" infinities can be anything, that is, it is not well-defined. Assemble like expressions in your solution to get 
$$
T_1=T_0e^{kL}+A\left(L-\frac {e^{kL}-1}k\right)+B\left(1-e^{kL}\right).
$$
Then the  $A$ term is the difference between derivative and difference quotient which indeed goes to zero for $k\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for rearranging the terms, it looks a lot better.  However I cannot see how this shows the solution of $T_1=T_0$ when $k\to0$

Comment: Apply the mean value theorem for $f(x)=e^{xL}$, then $\frac{e^{kL}-1}k=Le^{\theta kL}$ with $\theta\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You evaluation of the limit is wrong. By using the first order approximation $e^{kL}\approx1+kL$, the expression simplifies to $T_1=T_0+k(T_0-B)L$ and of course in the limit, $T_1=T_0$.

Comment: If you use the quadratic Taylor polynomial for the $A$ terms you get an additional term $-\frac12AkL^2$ which makes the approximation of $T_1$ correct up to $O(k^2)$ terms.

Comment: @LutzL: a first order development is enough as we are only concerned with the final constant term while the denominators have $k$ to the first power. The final $k^2$ terms are of no use (as well as the final $k$ terms).

Answer (score 0):

If $k=0$ then $T'=0\iff T=cst$

If $k\neq 0$ then homegeneous equation is $T'=kT\iff T=Ce^{kx}$

Constant variation to find a particular solution with RHS :

$\require{cancel}T'=\cancel{Cke^{kx}}+C'e^{kx}=k(T-T_0)=\cancel{kCe^{kx}}-k(Ax+B)\iff C'=-k(Ax+B)e^{-kx}$

$C=(Ax+B+\frac Ak)e^{-kx}+D$

> $T=Ax+B+\frac Ak+De^{kx}$

I think you complicate unnecessarily using your method.

---

*Edit: after problem fix and comment*

The solution for $k=0$ is still valid, we get $T=T_0$ and this forces $T_1=T_0$.

When $k\neq 0$ we have to work initial conditions :

We have

$\begin{cases}
T_0=B+\frac Ak+D \\
T_1=AL+B+\frac Ak+De^{kL}=T_0+AL+D(e^{kL}-1) \\
\end{cases}$

Since $A,B$ are constants independent of $k$, the limit condition $\lim\limits_{k=0}T_1=T_0$ implies that $D$ actually depends on $k$.

$T_1=T_0+AL+D\underbrace{(1+kL+o(k)-1)}_{\text{Taylor Expansion of exponetial}}=T_0+\underbrace{(AL+kDL)}_{\text{need to be }0}+\underbrace{o(kD)}_{\text{need to }\to 0}$

So we need $D=-\frac Ak$.

Substituting in $T$ we get :

> $T=T_0-\frac Ak\left(e^{kx}-1-kx\right)$

You can now check that this solution is continuous in $k=0$.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the incorrect use of $T_0$ in the first few lines.  It should be $T_{amb}$, please see correction.  $T_0$ is indeed the value of T at $x=0$ and $T_1$ is the value of T at $x=L$.  Your solution is not valid for $k\ne0$ since $T_{amb}$ is a function of $x$.  Also I cannot have 2 solution methods for $k=0$ and $k\ne0$, as I require continuity when $k\to0$ (which you do not have - substitute $k=0$ in your solution you will get $T\to\infty$).  Indeed the $k=0$ solution must be obtained from the general solution for any k.  This is what I have tried to solve above.

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: Sorry can't follow your solution. @LutzL answered it by showing the point in my solution where I went wrong.

Comment: I simplified it. Just wanted to show we both arrive at the same conclusion using different method. Here I conclude that $D$ depends on $k$ so I need to make a Taylor expansion of $e^{kL}$. In your answer you already have $D=-\frac Ak$ but you didn't made the Taylor expansion, so you simplified $\frac{e^{kL}}k(-A)$ with $\frac Ak$ forgetting a term in $AL$.